# What is the first known space in mathematics?

Tags: vector-spaces, soft-question, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, math-history

It is well known that there are many differents mathematical spaces we cite for example :Banach space and Hilbert space , Inner product space , ... Really i'm interesting to know the first  space  which is appeared and was discovred in mathematics ? I have checked [History of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)) about space but i didn't get the first discovred space

Comment: Have you checked [Euclid's Elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_Elements)?

Comment: I would assume the first space to appear was the Euclidean plane. I believe the terminology "space" is relatively recent.